# changing UIBarButtonSystem color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to change the color of a `UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay` for example or any other systems button? I checked the documentation and there isn't a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave said, you can change the tint color for any `UIBarButtonItem`. If you're adding the button in IB, you'd have to go under **Attributes** in Inspector. Under **Bar Button Item** you can decide the the Style, and the Tint color.

Alternatively, here I am adding a brown play button programmatically to toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *play =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay 
                                                                     target:self 
                                                                     action:@selector(playSomething)]; // if you want to do something when play pressed
[play setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain]; // Other options are UIBarButtonItemStyleDone or UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
[play setTintColor:[UIColor brownColor]]; // or whatever color u like


NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:play /*Other buttons like UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace can go here*/, nil];

[self setToolbarItems:items];
```

Keep in mind, you can be as creative as you want with colors, buttons, etc. I personally would prefer using small image icons as supposed to `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [tint color](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/tintColor) for UIBarButtonItems in iOS 5.